# Setting up a WL wallet based approach with Candy Machine V2

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I have been using the spl-token whitelist based approach via the the CLI with Candy Machine V2 up to this point. Sending WL users a token that is registered as the WL token in the Candy Machine config. This route has been ok but I would like to switch to a wallet based approach where wallet addresses are detected automatically without the need to send out tokens. I have been looking online for some documentation / notes on how this can be done but haven't been able to find much (might just be looking for the wrong thing). Is this possible to set up with Candy Machine V2? If possible, does anyone know of some good resources I can check out that could help me get this done? I would need the ability to set up multiple whitelists.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can do wallet based whitelisting with candy machine v2 together with gumdrop.

You would have to use claim-integration candy and distribution-method wallets. This will allow the given wallet to claim the wl token and since you are using claim integration candy will directly build the mint transaction, too. Therefore the user will only have to confirm one tx and would only see the wl token if the second transaction fails.

This is closest to what you can get to wallet based whitelisting with cm v2.

Keep in mind though that by default you have to give every user a personal claim link which contains a merkle proof that allows them to claim. Either use a discord bot where they can pull their claim link or modify the frontend to include the proofs and automatically fill it there.

Comment: I played around with this but I can foresee problems / many questions from people trying to figure out their claim link. Could become chaotic fast if the WL is large. Seems like a better experience for everyone with a straight wallet based approach.

Comment: you can build the proof into the website.
Detect the wallet, grab the proof and thats it. Will look like a wallet based mint for your user.

Or if you want it easier write a discord bot where they enter their wallet and get back their link.

I did both and both worked like a charm

Comment: OK yea both of those options could potentially work too. I like the idea of building the proof into the site if all the user has to do is send their wallet address and then the rest is taken care of. Is there any documentation or videos online about setting up these two approaches? I haven't been able to find anything outside of the basic gumdrop functionality

Comment: I am not aware of any video tutorial since it’s not just settings or similar but you would have to change the code in multiple locations. Read the connected  wallet. Read the json and split it into the proof parameters. Instead of using the query parameters use those for the transaction. Changes have to be done in claim.tsx; Regarding the discord bot you might be able to find someone who lets you use theirs if you ask in the metaplex discord

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to set up a Wallet-based whitelist using the deployed CandyMachineV2 Program. The only way of having this feature is grabbing the [CMv2 program](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/candy-machine/program) and update it to allow Wallet Whitelist instead of SPL-Token whitelist, then deploy your new CMv2 and use that new program ID in ur mint page and ur CLI to create and update the CandyMachine

Comment: OK yea if its possible to build it in I'd like to look into this option a little bit more